# Javascript Promise.all execution sequence question

Tags: javascript, settimeout, promise.all

When I execute the below Javascript promise.all() code I get the output as

```
hi
50
```

But is what I was expecting the output to be

```
50
hi
```

Can some one please explain me why "Hi" appeared first and then 50

Below is the code

```js
let p1 = Promise.reject(50);
let p2 = true;
let p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("hi")
  setTimeout(() => reject("hey"), 0);
});
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
  .then(values =>  console.log(values))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 3):

The callback you pass to `new Promise` will run synchronously, immediately, at the point you call `new Promise`. `hi` not only logs before the timeout, but also before you even call `Promise.all`.

The `setTimeout(() => reject("hey"), 0);` callback runs much, much later - only after that callback runs, and the Promise rejects, does the `.catch` get entered into and log the reject value.

In order for the logged values to be `50 hi`, you'd need to log `hi`

(1) after the `reject` call

(2) after another microtask (to give time for the `.catch` to run)

```js
let p1 = Promise.reject(50);
let p2 = true;
let p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject("hey");
    // queue microtask
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      console.log("hi")
    });
  }, 0);
});
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
  .then(values =>  console.log(values))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```